is there a way to run bazel tests in required sequence?
how to enforce bazel test targets to run in specific order on CI builds? because test results of one depends on another tetss results?
I have four targets init,up,down,rm and I want to run the tests targets of them in that order only i know bazel supports parallel runs by default .How to overcome that?
I tried with deps attribute and test_suite() rule but no luck

Does this answer your question? Does bazel support test execution order?
